# How can I remove all spiders in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It is possible to kill 1 spider by clicking while on console ... but I tried to kill all kind of them at once . so i created a batch file like this:

```
kill 00023aaa

kill 00023aac

kill 00041fb4

kill 00023aab

kill 00023aad

kill 0003a1e0
```

I placed their base ids but it doesn't work , all i can do is to select them and command kill, or use kill all.
is there any way to do that and then disable the corpses?

Answer (score 19):

For a comprehensive solution that can remove arthropods and insects entirely from the game, [**Insects Begone**](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/26468) is the mod for you. It removes these creatures, their webs, all their item drops, and every mention of them from spawn locations, loading screens, books, and vendor inventories, replacing them with properly-animated bears and rats and related items. It's modular too, so that those who don't want insects but don't mind arthropods, or who don't mind the webs but do mind their creators, can remove each part selectively.

Mod description:

> Mega Arachnophobia and Insect Phobia Mod. Renames and Replaces Spiders to "Invading Bears" and Chaurus to "Invading Skeevers". Removes Webs and Clutter Items. Renames and Replaces Chaurus/Spider items. Includes Failsafes incase any of this fails. All of this is optional and Modular with a NMM installer.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove the spider models from the game I think you could use this [mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/67855). It is supposed to replace all spiders with strange bear models. I know some people are very afraid of spiders. So I hope this helps.

**Edit:** The [insects begone](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/26468) mod seems to be even better than the mod I link to. Use that.

Comment: No help if you're also afraid of strange bears... :)

Comment: THE BEARS GET THEM OFF ME!!! The horrible hairy four legs... The two eyes! I need my bear replace mod! Make them spiders all of them.

But, really, some people are so afraid of spiders that they cannot play skyrim because the intro quest has them. Something to remember for any game developers out there :D.

Comment: There was a great mod that replaced all the spiders with Spidermen. *Spidermans?*

Comment: "*THE BEARS GET THEM OFF ME!!!*" @Ids You mean [this?](http://www.reddit.com/tb/knqcr) (Link is not to a picture of a bear.) =)

Comment: Whatever the first mod was, it's now gone.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will update it a bit.